# Saving Spark RDD to Avro with spark.api.python.Converter

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, avro

I am trying to follow [Spark 1.1: Bringing Hadoop Input/Output Formats to PySpark](https://databricks.com/blog/2014/09/17/spark-1-1-bringing-hadoop-inputoutput-formats-to-pyspark.html) guide to persist RDD in Avro format. My Converter works but looks really ugly.

```
class JavaToAvroWrapperConverter()
  extends Converter[Any, AvroKey[GenericData.Record]] {
  override def convert(obj: Any): AvroKey[GenericData.Record] = {
    val args: Array[Any] = obj.asInstanceOf[Array[Any]]
    val schema = (new Parser).parse(args(1).asInstanceOf[String])
    val map = args(0).asInstanceOf[Array[Any]](0).asInstanceOf[util.HashMap[String, Any]]
    val record = new GenericData.Record(schema)
    map.keys.foreach(k => record.put(k, map(k)))

    new AvroKey[GenericData.Record](record)
  }
}
```

for that to work I need to construct my RDD as a map of each row to the schema

```
to_avro_rdd.map(lambda x: ((x, avroSchema), None)).saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile(
        path + ".out",
        keyClass = "org.apache.avro.mapred.AvroKey",
        valueClass = "org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable",
        outputFormatClass = "org.apache.avro.mapreduce.AvroKeyOutputFormat",
        keyConverter="org.apache.spark.examples.pythonconverters.JavaToAvroWrapperConverter",
        conf=conf
    )
```

So, my question is whether there is a more civilized way to handle that without repeating schema in every RDD tuple and than getting it in a form of bulky parameters in converter. Or a short version of the same question would be: what am I doing wrong?

Thanks!